# Get mb information out of a frame

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-processing

Is there any way to get macroblock information out of a frame with ffmpeg library, such as macroblock size (it's a 16x16 or 8x8 or 4x4 mb), the amount of macroblocks of a frame and perhaps even the DCT coefficients or quantization parameters of a macroblock? I'm new to ffmpeg. I want to write a c program to extract those information on macroblocks. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: ffmpeg has a debug option which prints that info via the switches: of `pict`, `mb_type`, `qp`, `dct_coeff` ,as documented in this [section](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Codec-Options). Your best bet is to examine their corresponding [source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg).

Comment: cool! do you know where the corresponding source code is? or do you know how I can trace to find the corresponding source code?

Comment: except using a debugger, i meant

Comment: You can identify how those switches offset variables from this [file](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/options_table.h) and from where see where and how those variables are used.